# Add shadow to progress circle using react-native-svg

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-svg

I have a progress circle that I'm implementing with `react-native-svg` and the white circle indicates the target progress. However, sometimes the progress exceeds 100% and I want to create a `semi-circular` shadow on the top of the outer progress circle to indicate the excess value. So, for instance, if a progress is 150% I want to show a `semi-circular` shadow on the top of the progress at 50% (the excess). I tried to do it with `react-native-svg` library, but filters aren't supported yet. Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this? Any alternative solution?
[image]

An example is shown below of the expected behavior for 102%
[image]

Comment: Can you also add your current code to the question?